# window.open location=no works on one server, not on another?

Tags: javascript, window.open

Using the following code to generate a pop-up with no URL bar

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function open_on_entrance() {
            window.open('http://address.com', 'popsearch', 'resizable,dependent,status,width=1100,height=700,left=10,top=10')
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="open_on_entrance()">
```

Here's the crazy part - the code works when I run it on my model server, but the URL displays when the same code runs on the production server. This is when testing it from the same browser on a separate server.

I know some browsers don't allow the `location=no` tag, but is there a setting on a server that would disallow it?

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with the server it's served from; it runs in the browser. Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Cleared cache, closed window and tried new session, all parameters.  I can run the page on the prod server and it displays the URL, immediately tried it from the Model server and it does not show the URL.

There's more than a few pages that says it should not work at all (testing in IE 11) but yet there it is (or isn't) on Model, and working differently in Prod.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. However check the following things.

- You have cleared your browser cache.
- Your browser has blocked
  pop-ups.

The server does not affect the result of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which browser, but there's a funny setting in Internet Explorer which forces the URL bar to always show.  Make sure this is set to enabled!

IE 11/ 
Tools / 
Internet options / 
Security / 
(pick the right zone for your site, usually trusted) / 
Custom Level Under "Miscellaneous" / 
Under "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars" / 
Set to enabled